# Getting process from yesterday

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I want to obtain all the process that are running in the system, but only from yesterday.

I am using this, ps -eo etime,pid

but i need only list the process from yesterday, any idea?

INFO: active from yesterday, process actually running from yesterday

Thanks in advance

Comment: What means "from yesterday". Started yesterday? Ended yesterday?

Comment: active from yesterday, process actually running from yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the pids that have been running for more than 1 day but less than 2:

```
ps -e -o pid= -o etime= | sed 's/^ *//' | awk -F '[ -]+' 'NF>2 && $2==1 {print $1}'
```

if you want just more than 1 day, change it to `$2>=1`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you need
But if you needed it from a specific time, just add it to crontab.
For example:
0 2 * * *  ps -eo etime,pid>/tmp/processes.txt

This way you will have a snapshot from the processes running on 2:00

If you didnt mean that please be more specific of what exactly do you need

Comment: i want to know what procees are active from yesterday, not from today. only yesterday